# Easy to digest vs. Help with digestion

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Is the phrase "help with digestion" equivalent in meaning to the phrase "easy to digest", i.e. can I replace the former phrase with the latter in this sentence:

> Apple juice helps with digestion.

Additionally, can the phrase "help with running" be replaced by "easier to run" in this sentence:

> The shoes released just a couple of days ago really helps me with running.

Comment: 'Apple juice helps with digestion.' is a claim that could be tested in law, so one has to be sure of one's facts. 'Apple juice makes things easy to digest' goes further, and one would have to be **really** sure of one's facts ("I had a pint of apple juice, then ate a hamburger, and got heartburn" ... lawsuit?) // '... help me with my running' would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Do you mean 'apple juice [is] easy to digest' or, as Edwin suggests, 'apple juice [makes food] easy to digest'? Similarly, 'help with running' would need to be replaced with '_make it_ easier to run'.